# Filter dataframe to get name of the youngest of a particular gender

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, filtering

I waste 2 hours and shouldn't find solve to my problem.
I need filtering from csv Only name of female who has minimal age.

I do only this part, and don't know how i can combine my solve in one right solve. Can you please support me, and say what an attributes can help me in my problem.

Columns = ['name', 'gender', 'age', 'height', 'weight']

```
frame = pd.read_csv("h03.csv")
out = pd.DataFrame(data=frame)

filtr = frame[frame['gender'] == 'F']
min_age = filtr['age']
ne = frame.loc[frame.gender == 'F']
ne = frame[frame['age']==frame['age']].min()

print(ne)
```

Comment: So you're trying to find the name of the youngest female?

Comment: yes i trying...

Comment: If so, `frame.set_index('name')['age'].idxmin()` should work.

Comment: Thank you so much, now i will be learn how it work. <3

Comment: @richardec will only give you the first female with that age... if you had multiples and wanted to return all females with the min age, then you'll need to do it differently.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your data this should be a good enough starting point for you to put your own column names and data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Gender':['M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F'],
        'Age':[20, 21, 21, 13, 22, 13]
    }
)
df = df.loc[df['Gender'] == 'F']
df['Check'] = np.where(df['Age'] == df['Age'].min(), True, False)
df = df.loc[df['Check'] == True]
df
```

Answer (score 0):

> df = df.sort_values(by = 'age')
>
> df[df.Gender == 'F'].iloc[0].name